# Save & exit button validation

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I'm working on one project in which I have to create a signup page with two UIButtons very first button is "Save&Exit" and the second one "continue"..if I have not given any value in the text field and click onto the save&exit button then without showing any validation error I need it to be exit and save and if any of the field is filled then it should be according to validation that I've given

I've used the following code but not working properly...

```
 if (([first_name length] == 0) && ([last_name length] == 0 ) && ([user_name length] == 0 )  && ([email_address length] == 0 ) && ([phone_number length] == 0  ) && ([countryCode_number isEqualToString:@"Country Code"] ))

    {
        NSString *ContactString = [countryCode_number stringByAppendingString:phone_number];
        userDetails = [[ NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
        [userDetails setValue:first_name forKey:@"FirstName"];
        [userDetails setValue:last_name forKey:@"LastName"];
        [userDetails setValue:ContactString forKey:@"Phone"];
        [userDetails setValue:refer_code forKey:@"ReferCode"];
        [userDetails setValue:genderString forKey:@"gender"];
        [userDetails setValue:user_name forKey:@"UserName"];
        [userDetails setValue:email_address forKey:@"Email"];
        [userDetails setValue:self.dobTextField.text forKey:@"dob"];
        [userDetails setValue:self.headShotImagebase64str forKey:@"profile_image"];
```

I'm new to ios..so pls help me

Comment: Maybe you need to invert the logic of the if statement (with a single `!`)

Comment: can u pls explain

Comment: `if (!([first_name length] == 0) && ([last_name length] == 0 ) && ([user_name length] == 0 )  && ([email_address length] == 0 ) && ([phone_number length] == 0  ) && ([countryCode_number isEqualToString:@"Country Code"] ))`

Comment: not working for me..

Comment: try to explain your question clearly, so others can understand.

Answer (score 1):

check whether all the textfields are empty or not.
if textfields are empty no need to check for validation else you  need to check for validation.

Comment: although this code is working if all fields are filled otherwise only working for first name and last name... i need it to be worked for the rest of the fields if all of them are empty partially filled

Comment: @ios  check whether all the textfields are empty or not. if textfields are empty no need to check  validation else you need to check  validation for each and every field separately

Comment: ur not getting me...what I'm actually trying to say...look I Know that there is no need of validations if all the fields are empty but if I filled any one field I need it to be according to validations...

Answer (score 0):

Change your if condition with '>' simbol.

if([first_name length] > 0)

{

// Your code

}

Comment: u mean I've to write it separately??? don't you think so it will become so lengthy??

Comment: Not do it separate,  change all '==' into  '>'.

Comment: n if all the fields are empty then ?

Comment: but I want it to be saved and exit without showing any alert...if i filled any of the one field i need it to be filled according to validation otherwise simply save and exit